# Change Variable Value in While Looping

Tags: php

I want to know how to modify variable value each time while looping.

Please guide me what i am doing wrong in below coding.

```
$amount = 500;

while ($amount > 0) {
$a = $amount - 50;
echo $a . "<br>";
}
```

I am receiving this:

```
450 450 450 450 450 450 450 450 450
```

But i want that:

```
450 400 350 300 250 200 150 100 50
```

Comment: Why did you tag so many languagesssssss?

Comment: use `$amount  = $amount - 50`

Comment: you don't decrement $amount value, so it will be always 500 -> it's an infinite loop here

Comment: `$amount -= 50; echo $amount;`

Comment: Just for reference:  You have here a loop that you already know the start and end points of.  A `for` loop fits better here.  `for ($amount=450; $amount>=50; $amount-=50) { echo "{$amount}<br>"; }`, for example...which states the intent more clearly.  `while` is more primitive, and should be a second choice; it's more appropriate if you're iterating over an unknown(-til-runtime) set of values, and/or aren't exactly sure when the loop will end -- either condition being rather awkward for other control structures.

Comment: @cHao Can't you post this as an answer? :) nice :)

Comment: @bystwn22: I suppose i could...  :)  I just tend to shy away from "do it this whole other way" answers unless the current way is very wrong.  Here, it's just lacking semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the the `amount` in your loop, hence you are always getting the result as 450 form this statement:

```
$a = $amount - 50;
```

which evaluates all the time as $a = 500 - 50 = 450

Change your code like this:

```
$amount = 500;

while ($amount > 0) {
$a = $amount - 50;
echo $a . "<br>";
$amount  = $amount - 50;

}
```

Comment: A bit uglier than i was hoping for, but +1 for being the first one to actually explain the problem rather than just tell the OP what to type.  :P

Comment: @cHao I totally agree to the ugly part :-)

Answer (score 1):

A few of the answers here have mentioned how to get your `while` loop to work right.  Just so you know, though, there's a better way.

`while` is a lower-level control structure, and is OK when you need the flexibility.  For instance, it's good for loops where you don't know the number of iterations in advance.

Here, though, you already know the start and end points.  The first number you want is 450, the last is 50, and each number is 50 less than the one before.  `for` is *made* for cases like this.

```
for ($amount=450; $amount>=50; $amount-=50) {
    echo "{$amount}<br>";
}
```

It's also more self-contained, and a bit easier to get right, since all the code that modifies your loop variable is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$amount = 500;

while ($amount > 0) {
$amount = $amount - 50;
echo $amount . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $a = $amount - 50;
 $amount = $a;
 echo $a . "<br>";
```

instead of

```
$a = $amount - 50;
echo $a . "<br>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Juned already explain what's going on, i am posting a slightly smaller code version

```
$amount = 500;

while ($amount > 0) {
   echo ($amount -= 50) . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: OP wants 450 400 350 300 250 200 150 100 50 , not -50 (which your answer returns). Downvoted. Test before posting.

Comment: Its even smaller `while( $amount > 0 ) { echo ( $a  = ( $amount -= 50 ) )."<br>"; }` :\

Comment: @bystwn22 i don't know why you put an `a` there

Comment: Thats not needed, but see the question, without `a` its really small again :P

Answer (score -1):

You have change the value of $amount inside the loop
until it maintain the same value as it initialize

```
$amount = 500;

while ($amount > 0) {
$amount = $amount - 50;
echo $amount . " ";
}
```

Now you receive the following result as you desire

```
450 400 350 300 250 200.....
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$amount = 500; // You have assigned $amount = 500

while ($amount > 0) {
$a = $amount - 50;
echo $a . "<br>";
}
```

Now while $amount > 0 this loop runs. Each time loop runs there is no statement that is on the LHS. That is $amount is not being changed but always being just referenced.

To change amount you have to

```
$amount = $amount - 50; // 500 -50 = 450, next loop 450  - 50 = 400, next loop 400-50=350 and so on
```

Comment: @bystwn22 Hey stop wining. It is a typo